Decorate Pydantic BaseModel with dynamic field_serializer
I want to add field_serializers from Pydantic to all models using decorators applied to the classes. However I get the 'Circullar reference detected' error.
from typing import List, Union, Callable, Type
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_serializer
from pydantic_model import UmlPrimitiveType, UmlClass, UmlInterface, UmlDataType, UmlEnumeration, UmlVisibilityEnum


class UmlElement(BaseModel):
    id: str


class UmlIdReference(BaseModel):
    idref: str

    @classmethod
    def from_uml_element(cls: Type['UmlIdReference'], element: 'UmlElement') -> 'UmlIdReference':
        return cls(idref=element.id)


def pydantic_field_serializer_func(field: Union['UmlElement', 'UmlIdReference']) -> dict:
    return UmlIdReference.from_uml_element(field).model_dump() if isinstance(field, UmlElement) else field.model_dump()


def serialize_fields_to_id_reference(fields: List[str]) -> Callable:
    def decorator(original_class: Type[BaseModel]) -> Type[BaseModel]:
        for field in fields:
            field_serializer_func = field_serializer(field)(pydantic_field_serializer_func)
            field_serializer_func_name = f"{field}_to_json"
            setattr(original_class, field_serializer_func_name, field_serializer_func)

        return original_class
    return decorator




# This works
class UmlAttribute(UmlElement):
    type: Union['UmlPrimitiveType', 'UmlClass', 'UmlInterface', 'UmlDataType', 'UmlEnumeration', 'UmlIdReference'] 
    visibility: UmlVisibilityEnum = UmlVisibilityEnum.PUBLIC

    @field_serializer("type")
    def type_to_json(type: Union['UmlPrimitiveType', 'UmlClass', 'UmlInterface', 'UmlDataType', 'UmlEnumeration', 'UmlIdReference']) -> dict:
        return pydantic_field_serializer_func(type)
    

# This does not work
@serialize_fields_to_id_reference(["type"])
class UmlParameter(UmlElement):
    type: Union['UmlPrimitiveType', 'UmlClass', 'UmlInterface', 'UmlDataType', 'UmlEnumeration', 'UmlIdReference']

Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fpawlows/temp/pydantic_model.py", line 218, in <module>
    f.write(model.model_dump_json(indent=2))
  File "/home/fpawlows/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/main.py", line 415, in model_dump_json
    return self.__pydantic_serializer__.to_json(
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.PydanticSerializationError: Error serializing to JSON: ValueError: Circular reference detected (id repeated)

I changed from assigning the method in overrided init to just assigning to the class from the argument of the decorator. Unfortunatelly, it didn't help.

There is not enough here to reproduce your problem. Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example.
